# Notepad++: block paste has stoppped working

Tags: notepad++

I can select a block of text by holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd>  key while selecting the block with the mouse.

Used to be: if I placed the cursor where I wanted the block to appear -- say to the left of a bunch of lines of text -- and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>  it would place it there and move the existing lines to the right.

Now:  the paste acts like it is not a block of text.  It moves the existing lines to under the block

Example

```
111
222
333

AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Select the block of numbers in column mode, then paste in front of the block of letters,

Used to get:

```
111AAA
222BBB
333CCC
```

Now I get:

```
111
222
333
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Why has this stopped working? (Notepad++ v7.2.2 32-bit)

Thanks!

Alan

Comment: I've never known "paste" to work the way you're expecting.  I've always got the pasted text **before**, not preceding the text line by line.  I've tried some versions back to **6.9.1**, behaviour is always the whole block goes before (i.e. where the cursor is placed).  Do you know/remember a version where you got your expected behaviour?  Are you sure you were not using a plugin?

Comment: No repro with notepad++ 7.4

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jehad.  You are saying that the block paste behavior I wanted is not how the program works in its stock version?  I am sure that it worked that way before today.  But, of course, that does not mean that it did.  I get the behavior I expect from a block paste in the Winedt Editor for LaTeX.  Perhaps I'm confused. Has anybody else seen the behavior I wanted in Notepad++ or am I conflating two different programs?

Comment: @jehad It should work (and does in my notepad++ 7.4). That is what Column Mode is for. It doesn't require any plugins.

Comment: It works exactly as you describe in my notepad++ 7.4

Comment: Thanks David.  Do you mean that the block paste works for you as in my "used to get" example above or like the Now I get example?  I.e What were you not able to reproduce?

Comment: Any ideas what might be causing this to fail on my system.  I already a complete uninstall reinstall cycle.

Comment: @DavidPostill Column Mode (using Alt key) works for me as well (from vers 7.4 back to 6.9).  But, column mode pastes a copy of the entire clipboard at each line.  i.e. copying 3 lines and pasting next to 3 other lines, will result in 3x3(=9) lines.  As far as I know, there is no interlacing, as AlanPeters expects.  I'd be very interested to know if you can interlace (sorry if it's a bad name, not sure how else to refer to this behaviour) lines.  Would be very useful for csv files.

Comment: @AlanPeters I mean that is works for me as per your "used to get". I cannot repro "now I get".

Comment: @jehad Column mode insert for me gives what you called "interlaced", ie the "used to get " behaviour. I cannot repro the "now I get" behaviour.

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for editing the OP to make it clearer.  Having followed the instructions using <kbd>Alt</kbd> (while selecting the text to be copied), I am now getting the expected behaviour.  So, great feature, not sure why it is not working for AlanPeters.

Comment: @AlanPeters Note that you are missing <ctrl><c> before <ctrl><v>. Are you pasting something that was already on the clipboard instead of the column selection because you haven't done a <ctrl><c>?

Comment: Did you try on different computer?